# What is this black spot in Syria?

Tags: identify-this, landform

While browsing Google Earth in Syria, I noticed this black spot. I could not find any information about it. What is this spot? [goo.gl/maps/TGvdFsuZ6ux](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/33%C2%B002'06.7%22N+37%C2%B011'41.2%22E/@33.0351944,37.1927176,681m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d33.0352042!4d37.1947785)

[image]

Comment: Reddit had also no luck on finding it: https://www.reddit.com/r/geography/comments/1nx6ii/what_is_this_giant_black_feature_i_southern_syria/

Comment: Looks to me like Reddit had plenty of luck: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Safa_(Syria)

Comment: See also [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/is-this-a-former-volcano/14751#14751) on the [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) companion site.

Answer (score 17):

The area is called [Tulul Alsafa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Safa_(Syria)), Arabic for "Al-Safa hills".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Safa_(Syria)):

> is a hilly region which lies in southern Syria, north-east of Jabal Al-Arab volcanic plateau. It consists of a basaltic lava field of volcanic origin, covering an area of 220 square kilometres, and contains at least 38 cinder cones

What you have [zoomed in](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/33%C2%B002'06.7%22N+37%C2%B011'41.2%22E/@33.0351944,37.1927176,681m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d33.0352042!4d37.1947785) in the linked map is one of those 38 [cinder cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinder_cone).

Factoids: According to news reports, this area is where ISIS is "hiding" now (Sep 2018) after being hit by the Syrian army, it has unique geographical features which makes it hard for the army to follow them (according to the article I read).

Comment: If the OP's map shows a single cinder cone, then it is _curiously_ identical in shape and coloration to the entire 20-km-across lava field (which is clearly visible on both Google and Bing satellite views of Syria).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, he's probably referring to the view given by clicking through OP's link. That is more zoomed in than the image in the question post.

Comment: Good. ISIS can sit in there until they run out of something.